# How to avoid jquery fancy box and mouse scrolling conflicts

Tags: jquery

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <?php include("fancybox/fb.php"); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    /*
     *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings

     */
    /*scroll page*/

     $('#testDiv').slimScroll({
          railVisible: true,
          railColor: '#f00'
      });
      jQuery.noConflict();
     $('.fancybox').fancybox();


/*fancy Box */   
     $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        closeBtn  : false,

        helpers : {
        title : {
        type : 'inside'
        },
        buttons : {}
        },

        afterLoad : function() {
        this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
        }
        });




        });


        </script>
```

Comment: give URL of ur site,Please dont say its on localhost.

Comment: Reaily it is localhost

Answer (score 0):

slimScroll plugin emulates scroll by handling mousewheel event over scrollable area and may be the reason of JS conflict with native scrolling or other js code. Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) that uses native browser scrolling without handling/preventing mousewheel event. Or try any of scrollbars with type *Native* from this [scrollbars comparison table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing)